# Cannot retrieve inbox messages when re-installing app or installing on second device

Tags: mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

When implementing Inbox Messaging using MarketingCloudSDK iOS (v8.0.7), I have observed that when a Contact installs the app on a second device, previous sent messages are not available on the new device. For example:

1. User installs app
2. Device is registered for ContactKey
3. Send inbox messages to device
4. Messages are received in mobile app
5. User deletes app and re-installs, or installs app on a second device (e.g. tablet)
6. Device is registered for same ContactKey as per step 2

**Result:** Previous inbox messages are not available

Is this expected behavior? And if so, what is the solution to retrieve these messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working as expected. Sends are device specific and device identifiers do not persist an uninstall.

See your account representative regarding per-contact Inbox messaging.